# Installing MySQL as database for airflow - password issue

Tags: server, mysql, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64) on WSL2.

I'm following this guide to install Mysql and have reached step 4 where I have chosen MEDIUM and was prompted to enter a new password.

(https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-mysql-ubuntu-20-04)

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.
The 'validate_password' component is installed on the server.
The subsequent steps will run with the existing configuration
of the component.
Please set the password for root here.

New password:

Re-enter new password:

Estimated strength of the password: 100
Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
 ... Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.
```

then it keeps me asking me for a new password with this error.

Later on, when I try to use these commands for setting up a MySQL database:

```
CREATE DATABASE airflow_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE USER 'airflow_user' IDENTIFIED BY 'airflow_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON airflow_db.* TO 'airflow_user';
```

from https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html

I'm stuck on

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'airflow_user' IDENTIFIED BY 'airflow_pass';
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

I wonder if I need to do something similar to here?

[New MySQL install has no root password, and can't set one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352679/new-mysql-install-has-no-root-password-and-cant-set-one)

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

how can I solve this please?

Comment: With the medium password setting, you’ll need something with upper and lower case characters, a number, and a special character. If memory serves, the length will need to be 10 characters or more. The “super secret” that you had in the question will satisfy this requirement 

Comment: yes, I have all this. my estimated password strength is 100.