# Is mysql_secure_installation necessary for MySQL 8?

Tags: server, mysql

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu server to 22.04. When I installed `mysql-server` I was getting root errors and could not log in, I came up with some posts like the following:

[New MySQL install has no root password, and can't set one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352679/new-mysql-install-has-no-root-password-and-cant-set-one)

[MySQL root password setup error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406395/mysql-root-password-setup-error)

So it appears I can just do `sudo mysql` and then create a different user from `root` with all privileges, after that maybe I should remove `root` user?

So my question is, do I have to do a `mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: Have you done  a Threat/Risk Analysis? As initially asked, your Question can only be answered with Yes/No/Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you plan to use your MySQL for. It enables you to improve the security of your MySQL installation. Using `mysql_secure_installation` is not required, but it is a very easy way to do some basic security on your MySQL server. You can manually do everything `mysql_secure_installation` does, but why bother when there is a working tool for that?

So, if you are just running a MySQL server on your dev machine, it's probably not required. But if you are planning to use it in production or expose the server to the internet, running `mysql_secure_installation` is a bare minimum when we talk about security.

I recommend you to check the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-secure-installation.html